# What crops the response from the SocketListen based web server?

Tags: web-access, interoperability, socket

I noticed that when the response length passes around 1k characters then it is cut at weird lengths: 424, 936 or 1448 characters.

Response is generated correctly but then it is cut so if the body was eg. a JSON then it is malformed.

Any ideas?

```
Quiet @ Close @ listener;
responseBodyLength = 2000;

constResponse = ExportString[
   GenerateHTTPResponse @ HTTPResponse @ ExportForm[
     StringRepeat["a", responseBodyLength], "Text"
   ]
, "HTTPResponse"
];

listener = SocketListen[
   Automatic
,  With[{client = #["SourceSocket"]}, WriteString[client, constResponse]; Close@client] &
];

url = URLBuild[<|"Scheme" -> "http", 
   "Domain" -> First[listener["Socket"]["DestinationIPAddress"]], 
   "Port" -> listener["Socket"]["DestinationPort"]|>];
```

Test

```
Table[
  StringLength@URLRead[url, "Body"], 50
] // Counts
```

> ```
>  <|936 -> 13, 1448 -> 35, 424 -> 2|>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

It appears `WriteString` will return too quickly, so your message is closed in the middle of sending. In short, my current solution is to use an appropriate time to wait before `Close@client` (for example `Pause[.05]`).

On my system (version 13.2 on windows 11), the result is `<|936 -> 50|>`.

---

##### More details:

I've changed the message to see which part of the message is missing:

```
StringRiffle[Range[528], "-"]

(* Shorted Output: "1-2-3- ... -526-527-528" *)
```

which produces a **2003**-length string similar to your case.

`URLRead[url, "Body"]` results in the following string:

```
"1-2- ... -268-26"

(* StringLength[%]: 966 instead of 2003 *)


Table[StringLength@URLRead[url, "Body"], 50] // Counts

(* Out (usually): <| 966 -> 50 |> *)
```

But if you add `Pause[.05]` before `Close`ing the `client`, everything works as expected:

```
StringLength@URLRead[url, "Body"]

(* Out: 2003 *)


Table[StringLength@URLRead[url, "Body"], 50] // Counts

(* Out: <| 2003 -> 50 |> *)
```

If we change the message to `StringRiffle[Range[4000], "-"]` which produces a 18892-length string, we see `966` and `Pause[.05]` is not enough to transfer all the message.